# @EnableJpaRepositories is not present in spring boot 2.1.4.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I created a project using spring boot 2.1.4.RELEASE with the following dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

I have the following entity and repository:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "age")
    private Integer age;

    @Column(name = "createdAt")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createdAt;
...
}
```

PersonRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Integer> {

}
```

The following is my Application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringDataApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(SpringDataApplication.class, args);
        PersonRepository personRepository = context.getBean(PersonRepository.class);
        Person p1 = new Person("Juan", "Camaney", 55);
        Person p2 = new Person("Arturo", "Lopez", 33);
        Person p3 = new Person("Pancho", "Coscorin", 22);

        personRepository.save(p1);
        personRepository.save(p2);
        personRepository.save(p3);

        Iterator<Person> people = personRepository.findAll().iterator();
        while (people.hasNext()) {
            Person temp = people.next();
            System.out.println(temp);
        }
    }
}
```

If i execute my application i get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.devs4j.spring.data.repositories.PersonRepository' available
```

The solution of it is add the following configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.devs4j.spring.data.repositories")
public class JpaConfiguration {

}
```

But I get the error :

```
EnableJpaRepositories cannot be resolved to a type
```

If i downgrade to **2.0.5.RELEASE** everything works fine.

I'm confused because when i check the following spring documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/ I see that it is still using @EnableJpaRepositories("com.acme.repositories")

Am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: Did you declare `spring-boot-starter-parent` as the parent in the `pom.xml`?

Comment: No, because it is a hierarchical project, as you can see in the dependencies section I'm using :   <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

Comment: I have a multi-module project running with the latest Spring Boot version and it's working fine. In the top root parent project, I declared the `spring-boot-starter-parent` as its parent. You should consider giving it a try :)

Answer (score 0):

In your configuration.java, have you added the import:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
```